# composer installing packages command is not defined

Tags: composer-php

I have installed composer on my Synology NAS using [this](https://medium.com/unhandled-code/installing-composer-on-synology-6-1-4-eebd1a1c4891) tutorial. I did use PHP73 instead of PHP70 because the package I would like to install requires a minimum of PHP72. It all seems to run fine until I run the following command:

```
composer require duncan3dc/sonos
```

This gives me the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
Command "duncan3dc/sonos" is not defined.
```

I have already removed composer and reinstalled but without success, so currently my application requiring the package is broken. Very strange because it ran fine before and I don't see where I made changes that could be causing this.

Pretty new at composer btw. I'm running composer 2.0.7 btw.

Comment: That looks correct, and works on my system (PHP 7.3, same composer version 2.0.7). Have you tried manually adding the package to composer.json and running composer update?

Comment: Reinstalled using PHP70 which does work, but doesn't let me install packages since most of them require 7.1 or higher. Strange thing is when I run the composer --version command with PHP70 it shows the version like shown in the tutorial. With PHP73 it shows the help message, whatever the command.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct version of composer? This sounds a lot like it's not parsing command line argument correctly. Try re-downloading composer from https://getcomposer.org/download/ and make sure that's the one you are running, and there are no other versions installed elsewhere on your system.

Comment: Same results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding the following to my composer.json file and thus forcing composer to use a different version of PHP:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.3"
    }
}
```